# Are these false positives on this rkhunter log on linux?

Tags: xfce, manjaro, rootkit

I'm running Manjaro Linux with xfce,
I googled how to use the program and ran these commands to check for rootkits.

```
sudo rkhunter --update
sudo rkhunter --propupd
sudo rkhunter --check
```

But I'm not sure if the Warnings it gave are false positives or not. I'm particularly concerned about the warnings on lines 321,1729, and 1841.
[log file on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Qe5rKZnh)

Answer (score 0):

```
218. [23:29:36]   /usr/bin/egrep                                  [ Warning ]
219. [23:29:36] Warning: The command '/usr/bin/egrep' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/egrep: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable

221. [23:29:36]   /usr/bin/fgrep                                  [ Warning ]
222. [23:29:36] Warning: The command '/usr/bin/fgrep' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/fgrep: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable

243. [23:29:38]   /usr/bin/ldd                                    [ Warning ]
244. [23:29:38] Warning: The command '/usr/bin/ldd' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/ldd: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

False positives; `ldd` has always been a shell script on Glibc systems, and `egrep`/`fgrep` have always been shell scripts with GNU grep.

```
321. [23:29:49]   /usr/bin/vendor_perl/GET                        [ Warning ]
322. [23:29:49] Warning: The command '/usr/bin/vendor_perl/GET' has been replaced by a script: /usr/bin/vendor_perl/GET: Perl script text executable
```

False positive; *everything* in the `vendor_perl` directory is a Perl script. That's literally the purpose of this directory – it contains CLI scripts that come as part of Perl CPAN packages.

```
1727. [23:30:42] Info: Starting test name 'ipc_shared_mem'
1728. [23:30:42] Info: The minimum shared memory segment size to be checked (in bytes): 1048576 (1.0MB)
1729. [23:30:42]   Checking for suspicious (large) shared memory segments [ Warning ]
1730. [23:30:42] Warning: The following suspicious (large) shared memory segments have been found:
1731. [23:30:42]          Process: /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal    PID: 85027    Owner: user    Size: 1.0MB (configured size allowed: 1.0MB)
```

Most likely a false positive; PulseAudio used to create a few fairly large SysV SHM segments. Check `lsipc -s` or `ipcs` for more hints.

```
1840. [23:30:51] Warning: Hidden file found: /etc/.updated: ASCII text
```

False positive; it's a "flag file" used by a few systemd components to check whether some caches need to be rebuilt after a system update. The file's contents contain an explanation.

```
1841. [23:30:51] Warning: Hidden file found: /usr/share/man/man5/.k5login.5.gz: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 19
1842. [23:30:51] Warning: Hidden file found: /usr/share/man/man5/.k5identity.5.gz: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 22
```

False positives; those are just manual pages `man .k5login` (for the `~/.k5login` file) and `man .k5identity` (for the `~/.k5identity` file). You can read them using `zless <path>` or `man <path>`.